# Java: How to forcefully kill unneeded thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using some 3rd party code, which may hang indefinitely in some cases. This leads to hanging threads which keep holding the resources and clogging a thread pool.

Eventually thread pool becomes full of useless threads and system effectively fails.

In Java one can't forcefully kill the thread (kill -9). But how then to manage such edge cases?

Comment: when you say hang, what do you mean? Is it waiting for socket to respond back like DB call etc?

Comment: @SMA Let just say it enters an infinite loop. Or hangs on IO operation. Or something else I dunno. (it's a black box)

Comment: Well, you can at least "guess" what it is doing by doing a thread dump

Answer (score 2):

Obviously fixing the bug would be better, however alternative include

- only run the 3rd party code/library in a sub-process.  Just killing the thread is unlikely to be enough.
- you could hack the 3rd party code to check for interrupts in the sections you find run for too long.  You can take a stack trace to run out where this is.
- Use Thread.stop() though this has been disabled in Java 8.
- when you detect there is a hung thread, increase the size of the thread pool by one. This will give you the correct number of active threads.

Comment: `Thtread#stop()` is still there. Only `Thread#stop(Throwable)` has been disabled.